# Javascript closures (function)

Tags: javascript

```js
function outside() {
    let out = 0;
    function inside() {
        out += 1;
    }
    return inside;
}

let ref = outside();
console.log(ref());
```

Why do I get undefined when printed out instead of the value of the inside function which is 1 ?

Comment: Your `inside` function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inside` function must return the value.

```js
function outside() {
    let out = 0;
    function inside() {
        return ++out;
    }
    return inside;
}

let ref = outside();
console.log(ref());
```